# scrapy css selector chain how to represent current node?

Tags: python, css, scrapy

e.g. Given this [url](https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00RQ83FGU/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new)

I wanna get the seller's div

With Xpath, firstly I use css to get a specific seller row and then I use './' to refer current node, then I can get (5) divs that are placed immediately after my target div (row).

```
b = response.css('div#olpOfferList div.a-row.a-spacing-mini.olpOffer')[1].xpath('./div')
```

result of b:

```
<Selector xpath='./div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span2 olpPriceCol'>
<Selector xpath='./div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span3 olpConditio'>
<Selector xpath='./div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span3 olpDelivery'>
<Selector xpath='./div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span2 olpSellerCo'>
<Selector xpath='./div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span2 olpBuyColum'>
```

But with css, I don't how to refer current node after selecting the current node

```
a = response.css('div#olpOfferList div.a-row.a-spacing-mini.olpOffer')[1].css('div > div')
```

result of a:

```
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span2 olpPriceCol'>
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span3 olpConditio'>
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-section a-spacing-small">\n'>
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span3 olpDelivery'>
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span2 olpSellerCo'>
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span2 olpBuyColum'>
<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::div/div' data=u'<div class="a-button-stack">\n           '>
```

I tried this but getting a error:

```
a = response.css('div#olpOfferList div.a-row.a-spacing-mini.olpOffer')[1].css('> div')
```

How can I refer to current node with css? :D thanks for helping!

Comment: only with Xpath; CSS HAS NO ANCESTOR OR PARENT, this might be a usefull cheat sheet link between CSS and XPATh http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that without an XPATH selector at the end.

So what you use is correct

```
b = response.css('div#olpOfferList div.a-row.a-spacing-mini.olpOffer')[1].xpath('./div')
```

Since css has no way of referring current node or parent node, you will have to use an XPath only.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my puzzle!